# Applying a pytorch CNN to video?

Tags: pytorch, image-recognition

I am looking for some advice on how to apply a pytorch CNN to a video as opposed to an image.

Picture a drone flying over an area and using video to capture some objects below. I have a CNN trained on images of objects, and want to count the objects in the video.

Currently my strategy has been to convert the video to frames as PNGs and running the CNN on those PNGs. this seems inefficient, and I am struggling with how to count the objects without duplicating (frame 1 and frame 1+n will overlap).

It would be appreciated if someone had some advice, or a suggested tutorial/code set that did this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: PNGs are not designed for photography. You're going to be wasting a ton of space and due to hard disk access speeds you'll be spending more time reading the frames. At the very least you should be extracting your images as JPG. Deep networks are robust to compression artifacts and IMO the increased speed and decrease space requirements far outweighs any benefits from lossless compression of png.

Comment: Loading videos efficiently generally requires careful consideration and will depend on how you've designed the ML algorithm. For some tasks the best I've been able to do is write custom dataloaders which use temporal locality and a certain amount of caching to minimize the necessity to re-read the same frames multiple times. This can get especially complicated if you only plan to send crops of certain frames, rather than the entire frame.

Answer (score 0):

PyTorch at the moment doesn't have [support to detect and track objects](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/io.html) in a video.

You would need to create your own logic for that.

The support is limited to read the video and audio from a file, read frames and timestamps, and write the video read more in [here](https://pytorch.org/blog/pytorch-1.2-and-domain-api-release/#torchvision-04-with-support-for-video).

What you will basically need to do is to create an object tracking, frame by frame together by keeping their with their square positions and based on that decide if the same object or not.

If you have a drone flying and inspecting people you may check [Kinetics](https://deepmind.com/research/open-source/kinetics) to detect human actions:

- ResNet 3D 18
- ResNet MC 18
- ResNet (2+1)D

All based on [Kinetics-400](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.11248)
But the newer one is [Kinetics-700](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.06987).

Answer (score 0):

try using torchvision and torch to recognize objects in a youtube video

https://dida.do/blog/how-to-recognise-objects-in-videos-with-pytorch